# Windows couldn't be installed on current drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, uefi, windows-installation

I'll try to install Windows 10, 64 bit, 1703 on my despktop but got next error:

> Windows couldn't be installed on the current location. Check the station. Next is happen: 0x80300024.

The installation happens from a DVD I've written with an ISO file I've downloaded from the Media Creation Tool.

My computer two stations. One SSD from 119.2 GB and one hard drive that have two partitions of 914.0 GB and one of 17.5 GB for recovery. I'll install Windows 10 on the first station.

I'll install Windows on the first station.

I've cleaned the first station using this commando's:

```
DISKPART
select disk 0
clean
create partition primary
```

I've also checked the hard drives inside the HP PC Hardware Diagnostics UEFI and all tests have passed.

Comment: Remove HDD and install it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar issue today, where an older drive had partitions with a 'Master Boot Record'.

At the drive selection screen, ensure you remove any old partitions from the install drive before trying to install windows 10. If you need the recovery data, use an imaging tool (macrium or similar) to back the partition first, then wipe it from the drive.

I've found it best not to create partitions, and get Windows 10 sort it, after you've deleted the existing partitions.